# Altium Automatically fill Description and Comment with values from parameters

Tags: altium

I have made a full schematic with misplacing description and comment.

Is there a way to automatically make that Comment get filed automatically with Manufacturer Part Number (after having imported the components from the Supplier Search module into schematic) for all components inserted in the schematic ?

Same question for Description to fill with components description .

Comment: It is your 20th (or more) question about Altium, and I think that many has told you about reading Altium Tehcdocs. But it seems to me that you do not check them before asking. [Supplier Research Panel](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Supplier+Search+Panel) documentation will lead you to [Live Supplier Data](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Live+Supplier+Data+-+Import+to+Libraries+and+Schematics#DPIO) which holds the answer. Unfortunately too long to copy here.

Comment: Let me rectify the question, I forgot to mention something important which you didn't see I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to be able to automatically put the manufacturer part number (from the part parameters) in the "comment" field for all schematic components. This can be done by following these steps:

**1) Select all components in the schematic**

The easiest way to do this is right-click on one of them, click "Find similar objects", and set "Part" to "Same". Make sure the "Select Matching" checkbox at the bottom is checked, and click "OK". This will select all objects of type "Part"

**2) Set the comment field**

In the "Part Comment" field, simply type "=PartNumber" (or whatever your part number parameter is called). This will automatically place the value of the "PartNumber" parameter into the "Comment" field.

**3) Press Enter**

This should apply the change to all of your components.

Please note this will only work if all of your components have the same part number parameter name. Otherwise you have to do it manually. There is a reason I recommend building your own libraries -- It ensures the styles (like parameter names) are all identical and you can make changes like this much more easily.