# Altium: How to change several components at once in order to save time and effort?

Tags: schematics, altium

I am drawing a schematic in Altium Designer. Sometimes, I need to change some components from one value to onther. For example, I have 10 capacitors of 1 pF and need to change them all to 2 pF. Is it possible to do it at once instead of change each capacitor separately. 
This will of course help me to save time and effort !!

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245955/altium-automatically-fill-description-and-comment-with-values-from-parameters

Comment: SHIFT+F+L click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Learn to love "Find Similar Objects". Right-click on the object, change 'Value' from 'Any' to 'Same' and it should find all the 1pF capacitors.

It will highlight them when you click apply, and if that's right (and it should be, unless there are more than one type of 1pF capacitor, in which case you should apply some distinguishing feature) then click 'okay' to bring up the SCH inspector dialog.

You can then change the value to whatever you like, as well as change many other characteristics. The changes are applied immediately, not through the usual validate and execute.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I use "Find Similar Objects" and "SCH Inspector" all the time. It makes things MUCH easier and faster to update.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Thanks, always appreciate your Altium answers. I guess you don't do contract work since there's no contact info in your profile.

Comment: Thanks for the sentiment. I do not do official contract work (I'm not sure my current job allows it) but I have been known to help out family and friends with their projects. Maybe I should look up the company policy on external contract work....

Comment: Guess that answer will only help me if I want to change the value, but if I want to change the whole component, not just the value ?!

Comment: What aspects of the component do you want to change? The type? The component reference? You can change these in the SCH Inspector too (select the "Library" and specify the "Symbol Reference" to change it to a different component. You'll also want to change the Design Item ID and the Current Footprint)